# ImportError: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found

Tags: centos, software-installation, shared-library, datascience-anaconda

I am trying to install Hue on Centos 6.6 and configure it to point to a cluster that is running on Centos 7. The `yum` installation does not work on Centos 6 and hence I am trying to do the installation from source as given [here](https://github.com/cloudera/hue). When I do the `make apps` command, I get after a lot of warnings:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /root/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml-3.3.6-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/lxml/etree.so)
make[1]: *** [/root/hue/desktop/desktop.db] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/hue/desktop'
make: *** [desktop] Error 2
```

I installed python 2.7.12 using anaconda install. I can clearly see `Installing LIBXML2-2.9.2-0 being installed. Not sure why this error is occuring.

[image]

I also get this error import eror where zlib is not imported but this can also be seen installed during the anaconda install. should I make any configuration settings. All i did while installing Anaconda was download the .sh script and run it using bash (as mentioned in the website of continuum analytics).

Someone please help me understand and resolve this issue.